# Creating a AVFrame from a QVideoFrame

Tags: c++, qt, ffmpeg, libav, qtmultimedia

I'm struggling with converting a QVideoFrame (QT) into a AVFrame in order to encode video coming from a webcam.

Documentation for QVideoFrame: http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qvideoframe.html

I understand the basics of image formats, stride and such but I'm missing something. This is what I've got so far, adapted from a libav example (https://libav.org/doxygen/release/0.8/libavformat_2output-example_8c-example.html):

```
static void fill_yuv_image(const QVideoFrame &frame, AVFrame *pict, int frame_index, int width, int height)
{
    pict->pts = frame.startTime() * 1000000.0; // time_base is 1/1000000
    pict->width = frame.width();
    pict->height = frame.height();
    pict->format = STREAM_PIX_FMT; //todo: get this from the frame
    pict->data[0] = (uint8_t*)frame.bits();
    pict->linesize[0] = frame.bytesPerLine();
}
```

After which I'm attempting to encode:

```
AVPacket pkt;
int got_packet_ptr = 0;
int success = avcodec_encode_video2(c, &pkt, picture, &got_packet_ptr);
/* if zero size, it means the image was buffered */
if (success == 0) {
    /* write the compressed frame in the media file */
    ret = av_interleaved_write_frame(oc, &pkt);
} else {
    ret = 0;
}
```

It's returning an error about the stride not matching. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: What colorspace are you receiving from the camera, and what color spaces are supported by your chosen codec? Im guessing you need to convert from RGB to YUV.